# Flutter Slidable Inside Container

Tags: flutter

I am using flutter_Slidable and I want to achieve that the slidable is inside my container like in the example below:
You can see that in my example, since i have a border radius, there is a corner that doesn't look good.

How it is: You can see the corner that does look bad.
[image]

How it should be: Here you can see (AutoScout24 App) that the Slidable is inside the Container with the border Radius. That how i want it.

[image]
My code:

```
SizedBox(
            height: screenHeigth,
            width: screenWidth,
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: devices.length,
                itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                  var device = devices[index];
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                    child: Slidable(
                      key: const ValueKey(0),
                      endActionPane: ActionPane(
                        motion: const ScrollMotion(),
                        dismissible: DismissiblePane(onDismissed: () {}),
                        children: const [
                          SlidableAction(
                            onPressed: null,
                            backgroundColor:
                                Color.fromARGB(255, 191, 191, 191),
                            foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                            icon: Icons.edit,
                            label: 'Edit',
                          ),
                          SlidableAction(
                            onPressed: null,
                            backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFE4A49),
                            foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                            icon: Icons.delete,
                            label: 'Delete',
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),

                      // The child of the Slidable is what the user sees when the
                      // component is not dragged.
                      child: Container(
                        height: screenHeigth / 3,
                        width: screenWidth,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                          //border: Border.all(width: 2),
                          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
                        ),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Flex(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                direction: Axis.horizontal,
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    child: ClipRRect(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                      child: Image.network(
                                        '',
                                        width: 150,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    device.device.localName,
                                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(height: 32),
                              Flex(
                                direction: Axis.horizontal,
                                children: [
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: FittedBox(
                                      child: Text(
                                        device.device.remoteId.toString(),
                                        style:
                                            const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

Maybe you can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the rounded corner from the inner `Container` to the `Slidable`

```
return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
  child: ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
    child: Slidable(
      key: const ValueKey(0),
```

and

```
child: Container(
  height: screenHeigth / 3,
  width: screenWidth,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    //removed
    // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
    color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
  ),
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
```